# How to return rows that equal all substrings of a string

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I need to return all db-rows which match the following criteria:

```
SELECT col FROM tbl WHERE ALL 'reversed-sub-strings' of 'reversed-string' = col
```

Example:

some-string = 123456

should return rows that equal

6
56
456
3456
23456
123456

Of course we cannot use "WHERE col LIKE '%some-string' " because it would just return one row.
Also I am unwilling to create all the strings before sending them to the db.

I am using MySQL 5, maybe some Regex would help?

Comment: sounds like a good problem for regex: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html Not sure exactly what your requirements are (eg what about '66'?)

Comment: Just the requirements above, reverse some-string, create all substrings, reverse these and look for matches in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, this should do what you want;

```
SELECT col FROM tbl WHERE INSTR(REVERSE('123456'), REVERSE(col))=1;
```